# Create an precise amount of ref after rerender

Tags: reactjs

I've come across a react hurdle.

1. I'm trying to render a component that creates the amount of subcomponents I want.
2. But those subcomponents need refs.
3. And the amount of components that will be rendered may vary and so will the amount of refs needed.
4. Also it is possible that the component may already have been rendered and may need to increase its amount of subcomponent those further increasing the amount of refs needed.

**The problem**

The problem is that I can not create those refs in the exact amount I want because.

1. It happens after render.
2. The order in which it happens does not allow for my refs to be created before a rerender.

**What I've tried so far**

In order to do so I have my index component with which on the pressing of the key c calls a function (an useImperativeHandle). This function either tries to change one state by storing all the info needed for the render of the subcomponents(like the refs).

With this method I get the error that hooks can only be called inside component functions (the useRef in this case).

```
const newSoldiersAmount = (soldierInfos.numberOfSoldiers || 0) + nbAllies
  const newObjectRefs = [...new Array(newSoldiersAmount)].map((el) => useRef())
  const newRefs = [...new Array(newSoldiersAmount)].map((el) => useRef())
  let newSoldierInfo = {
    numberOfSoldiers: newSoldiersAmount,
    listOfAlive: [...new Array(newSoldiersAmount)].map((el) => true),
    objectRefs: newObjectRefs,
    refs: newRefs
  }
  setSoldierInfos({ ...newSoldierInfo })
```

I've tried useEffect which results in the same problem.

I've also tried another approach where I just set the amount of subcomponents I want to render and creating the refs directly from this number but then I get the error React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by ForwardRef.

```
const mycomponent = forwardRef((props,ref)=>{
  let objectRefs = [...new Array(soldierInfos.numberOfSoldiers || 0)].map((el) => useRef())
  let refs = [...new Array(soldierInfos.numberOfSoldiers || 0)].map((el) => useRef())
/*the rest of the code*/
```

**The code**

I've put my code in this codeSandbox :
[the codesandbox where my code is](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-three-fiber-wildlife-nrbnq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a way to make it work

i just used createRef (introduced in react 16.3) instead of useRef which gives me the code :

```
const newSoldiersAmount = (soldierInfos.numberOfSoldiers||0)+nbAllies;
let newSoldierInfo = {
                        numberOfSoldiers : newSoldiersAmount,
                        listOfAlive : [...new Array(newSoldiersAmount)].map(el=>true),
                        objectRefs : [...new Array(newSoldiersAmount)].map(el=>createRef()),
                        refs :[...new Array(newSoldiersAmount)].map(el=>createRef())
                    }
setSoldierInfos({...newSoldierInfo});
```

I've also read that there might be a way to do this by creating one ref and putting subrefs into it :

[source of the approach described in the above line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036453/creating-refs-inside-a-loop)